# Clickable div inside another clickable div

Tags: html, css

I have a div that is clickable and when I hover over this div another clickable div appears. However when I try to click this new clickable it will trigger only the parent div clickable. How do I make it to where I can click the new button instead of the parent div clickable?
[image]

Comment: Best would be to overthink your UI, don't use divs for click events, use buttons. And don't nest them. This creates weird stuff like you have like now.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback! I uploaded a picture of what I am trying to accomplish. I am attempting to make a Gmail clone. The part I am referring to is where you hover over an email and a small menu on the right side appears. So, you are saying to make these but buttons but then just add my content inside? @cloned

Comment: You got some answers already which should point you in the right direction. Just wanted to add: None of these elements should be divs. The icons should for example all be button elements and not divs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the one you're looking for https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_event_stoppropagation (in this demo, you need to tick on the checkbox on UI)

You can put `e.stopPropagation()` in your child element's click.

According to [this document](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_stoppropagation.asp)

> The stopPropagation() method prevents propagation of the same event from being called. Propagation means bubbling up to parent elements or capturing down to child elements.

Answer (score 3):

You have to set `stopPropagation` to the second div inside the click function.

```
function div(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
}
<div onClick='div()'>
```

This will solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

Call the following methods in the click handler for the nested div, and it should stop propagation to the parent click event

```
e.preventDefault();
e.stopPropagation();
```